# Convert String to custom Class Type in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, subclassing

Most of the search results I've found have turned up to be the opposite of what I'm looking for so here's my question:

I'm trying to convert System types into custom types of my own but as I mentioned, my search results have not been effective and give me the opposite of what i'm looking for.

Say I have a String of "mystringgoeshere" and a class like:

```
Class MyStringType

    Dim str As String

End Class
Dim s As MyStringType = "mystringgoeshere"
```

And i get this error {Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Project1.MyStringType'.}

I don't have any code yet really because I have no idea how to achieve this, but essentially what I want to do is set the "s" object's "str" string using a method like what i have in the code block above. I've tried using a "new(data as String)" subroutine, but it doesn't work with what i am trying.

Any ideas? thx~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this [VBCity Article on creating Custom Types](http://vbcity.com/blogs/jatkinson/archive/2010/01/12/create-custom-types-and-initialize-them-without-the-new-keyword-c-vb-net.aspx) It is using the [Widening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz3wbx3x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Operator.

from last link:

> Widening conversions always succeed at run time and never incur data loss. Examples are Single to Double, Char to String, and a derived type to its base type.

so try something like this

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim s As MyStringType = "mystringgoeshere"
        Dim s1 As MyStringType = "Hello"
        Dim s2 As MyStringType = s1 + s
    End Sub
End Class

Class MyStringType
    Private _string As String
    Private Sub New(ByVal value As String)
        Me._string = value
    End Sub
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As String) As MyStringType
        Return New MyStringType(value)
    End Operator
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _string
    End Function
    Public Shared Operator +(ByVal s1 As MyStringType, s2 As MyStringType) As MyStringType
        Dim temp As String = s1._string + s2._string
        Return New MyStringType(temp)
    End Operator
End Class
```

Comment: WORKS GREAT! Thx a bunch~! btw what would i change to do stuff like this--> Dim s as MyStringType = "566" + "98"  (which would result in passing the two strings to my class to be handled) would that be too complicated for this setup?

Comment: @user1666788 right now your second example would combine the two strings and create a MyStringType that was equal to "56698". If you want to do that with MyStringTypes you will have to override the + Operator. If you want something different you will need to explain what you want a little more.

Comment: great cool! and yes that's what i had in mind.(This project might seem tedious, but it's actually for a more complex one I have in mind that actually handles the math for my custom type to add/divide/subtract or what have you) Thx a bunch for your help I appreciate it :)

Comment: @user1666788 I added the + operator override code to answer, see if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
just change ur code little bit like this :

Class MyStringType 
    Dim str As String 
    Sub New(ByVal str1 As String) 
         str = str 
    End Sub 
End Class

Dim s As New MyStringType("abhi")
```

Comment: True that would work in some cases, but I want to use math and such on my type not just set it to something initially. but nice of you to try  :)

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is

```
Class MyStringType

    Dim str As String

End Class
Dim s As MyStringType 
s.str = "mystringgoeshere"
```

Comment: This post was to get around doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to subclass System.String. This is a fundamental of OOP programming. Inheritance is PRETTY important.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)