# Custom Type, derived from String

Tags: vb.net

I am dealing with an API which responds to my POST requests under the following format:

> Base64String:AnotherBase64String:Another:Etc

I have therefore some `Functions` and `Extensions` which take/return strings under the following format:

- Base64 Strings
- Base64DoubleDotsBase64 Strings (see above)

Things are getting quite messy, in the sense that when a function takes a `String` as an input, it takes some time (reading the Function doc) to check if the `String` should be a string, or a Base64 string, etc. The intellisense for `Strings` `Extensions` is also getting invaded.

I am considering deriving two new `Types` so that things are easier.

`String` is `NotInheritable`, so I am enclined to use the following:

```
Class Base64String
    Dim str As String
End Class
```

Is that OK? It seems so simple (and beautiful), I am nervous.

PS: my Base64 Strings will not require any operations such as concatenation. The only extensions required will be custom made. However, if there is a way to get the native extensions for string to work, I would be interested to know (out of curiosity).

Comment: That class is fine in that it is a valid class, but it depends where and how you intend to use it. You can use it where a `String` is expected because it's not a `String`. Whenever you do use it, you will have to get the value of that field (which should be a property) in order to have a value you can use where a `String` is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Hall's post mentions Widening in [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263991/10794555), which is just what I needed:

```
Public Class Base64String

    Private _String As String

    Private Sub New(ByVal value As String)
        Me._string = value
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal value As String) As Base64String
        Return New Base64String(value)
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _String
    End Function

    Public Shared Operator &(ByVal s1 As Base64String, s2 As Base64String) As Base64String
        Dim temp As String = s1._String & s2._String
        Return New Base64String(temp)
    End Operator

End Class
```

To be used like this:

```
Dim MyString As Base64String = "abcd"
Console.WriteLine(MyString)
```