# System.String to implement a custom Interface

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an `Interface` which defines a set of classes which all implement the `.ToString` member.
How can I make the native Data Type `String` implement this `Interface` as well?

First I am not sure how I would do it anyways, but something tells me that the fact that `String` is `NotInheritable` makes things even more difficult?

My tentative below: (an answer in C# is also acceptable)

```vb
Public Interface IString
    Function ToString() As String
End Interface

Partial Public Class String
    Implements IString

    Public Shadows Function ToString() As String Implements IString.ToString
        Return MyBase.ToString()
    End Function

End Class
```

---

### What I am trying to achieve

One of my subs should be able to take several Types as an input, one of them being the native `String` type.

```vb
Sub DoSomething(MyData as IString)
    '... Do something using MyData.ToString, for example send it to a WebAPI
End Sub

Public Class SomeData
    Implements IString 'Sub DoSomething should accept this type
    Public Sub ToString() as String
        Return 'Something
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SomeOtherData
    'Sub DoSomething should NOT accept this type
    Public Sub ToString() as String
        Return 'Something
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would like to avoid to have to do this:

```vb
Sub DoSomething(MyData as Object)
    If not TypeOf MyData Is String or not TypeOf MyData Is SomeData Then Throw New ArgumentException()
    '...
End Sub
```

I would like to avoid to have to do this:

```vb
Sub DoSomething(MyData as String)
    '...
End Sub

'Overload
Sub DoSomething(MyData as SomeData)
    call DoSomething(MyData.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do that? Everything in .NET already has a ToString method (it sits on System.Object)

Comment: How do you expect to be able to modify the String class to implement anything?

Comment: It is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54857526/10794555) where I created a `Base64String` type so that I can tell when my data is a Unicode String type, or a BytesEncodedIntoBase64 String type. Some of my functions should be able to take either as an `argument`. So I want to create an Interface which includes both. All I will need from the `Base64String` will be the `.ToString`, which returns a `String`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have no idea, that's why I'm here :)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do. A string is already a string, what do you want a `ToString` method to return?

Comment: I made some edits to explain further what I want to achieve

Comment: Sorry but it is still not clear what you are trying to achieve. The `IString` interface is superfluous as all types inherit the `ToString()` method. You can of course override what happens inside this method in your type. if you are working with base64 strings, then there are methods available to encode/decode a string.

Comment: I have a `Sub` or `Function` which should only be allowed to take variables of type `String` or `SomethingElse`. I want to avoid `Sub MySub(x as Object)` and I want to avoid having to `Overload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two alternative strategies for your dilemma:

1. Instead of different classes for different types of strings, just create a single class (e.g. SpecialString) that has two fields -- a string and an enum value to describe what type of string it contains (e.g. Normal, Base64, etc).  Then you can pass that class to the functions that need to be able to accept both types of strings but still be able to determine which type it is.  You can even write an implicit conversion (i.e. `Widening Operator CType`) from string to SpecialString so that you don't even need to explicitly create a SpecialString for normal strings.
2. If you want to keep the different types of strings as separate classes, you can create a base class (e.g. `AnyString`) that implements ToString. Then create `Base64String` as a class derived from `AnyString`. You can write an implicit conversion operator from `System.String` to `AnyString`.  Write your functions to accept `AnyString` if you want to accept both `String` and `Base64String`.  Or you can accept just a `Base64String` if you want to prohibit normal `String`s.

#### Example code for strategy 1:

```vb
Module Module1
    Enum StringType
        Normal
        Base64
        Base64DotBase64
    End Enum

    Class SpecialString
        Private type As StringType
        Private str As String

        Public Sub New(s As String, Optional type As StringType = StringType.Normal)
            Me.str = s
            Me.type = type
        End Sub

        Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal s As String) As SpecialString
            Return New SpecialString(s, StringType.Normal)
        End Operator

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return str
        End Function

        Public Function GetStringType() As StringType
            Return type
        End Function
    End Class

    'Function that uses SpecialString
    Sub Test(ss As SpecialString)
        ' Print StringType and inner value of string
        Console.WriteLine( ss.GetStringType().ToString("F") & ": " & ss.ToString())
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim ss1 As new SpecialString("abcdef", StringType.Base64)
        Dim ss2 As new SpecialString("abcdef:abcdef", StringType.Base64DotBase64)

        Test("Hello") 'Call with string
        Test(ss1) 'Call with Base64
        Test(ss2) 'Call with Base64DotBase64

        ' Pause to see the screen
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Expected Output:

```
Normal: Hello 
Base64: abcdef 
Base64DotBase64: abcdef:abcdef
```

#### Example code for strategy 2:

```vb
Imports System.Text.Encoding

Module Module1
    'Abstract base class to represent all string types (Normal and Base64 etc)
    MustInherit Class AnyString
        Private str As String
        Public Sub New(s As String)
            Me.str = s
        End Sub
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return str
        End Function
        ' Allow implicit conversion of a System.String to NormalString, which inherits from AnyString
        Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal s As String) As AnyString
            Return New NormalString(s)
        End Operator
    End Class

    'Class for Base64 strings only.
    Class Base64String
        Inherits AnyString
        Public Sub New(s As String)
            MyBase.New(s)
        End Sub
    End Class
    'Class for Normal strings. System.String implicitly converts to this.
    Class NormalString
        Inherits AnyString
        Public Sub New(s As String)
            MyBase.New(s)
        End Sub
        ' Allow implicit conversion of a System.String to NormalString
        ' This CType Operator isn't strictly necessary for this example, 
        ' because the CType in AnyString does the implict conversion shown below, 
        ' but it might be useful in general.
        Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal s As String) As NormalString
            Return New NormalString(s)
        End Operator
    End Class

    'Function that Accepts Base64String OR Normal String
    Sub TestAny(s As AnyString)
        'Call ToString for whatever type of string was passed.
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetType().Name.ToString()  & ": " & s.ToString())

        'Also do something special for base64 string
        If TypeOf s Is Base64String then
            Console.WriteLine("Base64 Decoded (in TestAny): " & DecodeBase64(DirectCast(s,Base64String)))
        End If
    End Sub
    ' Function to convert Base64-encoded string to normal text. 
    ' This ONLY takes Base64Strings (not NormalStrings)
    Function DecodeBase64(s64 As Base64String) As String
        Return UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(s64.ToString()))
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        'Normal String
        Dim s As new System.String("I am Normal")
        ' Base64String
        Dim s64 As New Base64String("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh")

        'Call TestAny with any type of string
        TestAny("Hi") 'Call with string directly
        TestAny(s)    'Call with String object
        TestAny(s64)  'Call with Base64DotBase64

        'Call DecodeBase64 with a Base64String ONLY
        Console.Write("Base64-Decoded (in Main): ")
        Console.WriteLine(DecodeBase64(s64))   'OK call with Base64String
        'Console.WriteLine(DecodeBase64("Hi"))  !!! Invalid -- cannot call DecodeBase64 with string
        'Console.WriteLine(DecodeBase64(s))     !!! Invalid -- cannot call DecodeBase64 with string

        ' Pause to see the screen
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Expected Output:

```
NormalString: Hi
NormalString: I am Normal
Base64String: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
Base64 Decoded (in TestAny): Hello World!
Base64-Decoded (in Main): Hello World!
```

Comment: " You can even write an implicit conversion (i.e. Widening Operator CType) from string to SpecialString". Interesting. How would I do that? At the moment my `Base64String` converts into `String` via `Widening Operator Type`, but I though `System.String` could not be touched?

Comment: The Widening Operator can be defined in the SpecialString class, so Strings can be automatically converted to SpecialString. I'll post some code.

Comment: It's true that you cannot modify System.String, but conversion (`CType`) operators can be defined on *either* of the classes, so you *can* add it to the custom SpecialString class (as shown in the code above). But as others have said, you cannot do anything to cause System.String to implement any new interface.

Comment: Sorry I was off the radar foe a while. The problem here is that we are shifting from multiple types being grouped into an interface, to multiple instances being grouped into a type. This means the formula which do not accept an IString but solely a Base64String type will need to be converted into 'function(s as Specialstring): If s.GetStringType <> x then Throw New Exception'. We are shifting the problem without really resolving it. I understand it can't really be resolved and to me the best approach is to Interface my custom types and overload the String type.

Comment: I want to avoid option 2 as well because it means the function would take a string type as an input, which is prone to misleading the programmer in the sense that they may not trivially understand the string can be a Base64string. To few people **fully** read the XML doc of a function

Comment: @Ama, No in strategy 2 the functions would take either an `AnyString` object or a `Base64String` object. If you use `AnyString`, it accepts both `System.String` objects (which are implicitly converted into `NormalString` objects) and `Base64String`s. But you can also have other functions that only accept `Base64String` to prohibit normal strings if desired.  I updated my post to add example code for strategy 2 to show this.

Comment: I see. I tend to forget `inherited` classes can be passed through a variable which is of the `base` class type. That is great and definitely the solution which fits best.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works:

Overload DoSomething as follows:

```
Sub DoSomething(MyData as String)
    '... Do something using MyData string, for example send it to a WebAPI
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(MyData as IString)
    DoSomething(MyData.ToString())
End Sub
```

When you call DoSomething with Native String, the first method will get called. and when you call DoSomething with object of type IString, the second method will be called, which internally calls the first DoSomething method with the IString.ToString() value as parameter

Comment: That is the workaround (see my update I think we wrote it at the same time), but is it just simply not possible to tell a native class to implement an `Interface` which I may have created myself?

Comment: how do we implement an interface on a class in a third pary library (read: .net framework)?

Comment: "read: .net framework" Can you be more specific? I did not find anything on the documentation, hence my question. And people seem tu suggest this is just not acheviable?

Comment: that is what I meant. As others said, we cannot implement an interface to a class that do not belong to us. string class belongs to .Net libraries.

Answer (score 0):

**In C#**

No, You can't modify the behavior of `.ToString()` function.

One thing that you can do is by using extension methods. But unfortunately, Extension methods are only checked if there are no applicable candidate methods that match. In the case of a call to `ToString()` there will always be an applicable candidate method, namely, the ToString() on `object`. The purpose of extension methods is to extend the set of methods available on a type, not to override existing methods; that's why they're called "extension methods". If you want to override an existing method then you'll have to make an overriding method. So simply you shouldn't use the name `ToString` for the Extension method as it will never be called because that method already exist and you shouldn't use `T` as it's useless there.

Here how you can write extension methods in C#

```
public static class ListHelper
{
    public static string ToMyString<T>(this IList<String> list)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
    }

    public static string ToMyString<T>(this String[] array)
    {
        return string.Join(", ", array);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

You cannot implement a custom interface on third-party class.

Comment: Thanks habib. I do not wish to modify the `.ToString` of the `String` type, I only wish to tell custom interface that `String` implements it.

Comment: @Ama Its not possible to implement the custom interface on a third-party library.

Comment: Thanks Habib, maybe that was the only reponse I needed from my original answer!